# WordPress function to call a spefic part of the page content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a simple website using WP and i don't know a way to call a specific part of the content. I'll try to explain myself better.

Using the function:

`the_content();` in the .php file i can call the whole page content. 
I'm using a shortcode that simply create a div and i want to call in the .php file only the div created so that i can put it inside other divs etc. 
Is there a function like `the_content();` that only calls the shortcode?

Or, without using the shortcode, is there a way to call a portion of the page content using a WP function?

Here's the code:

in the `function.php` i have:

```
function create_div($atts, $content = null) {

      extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'class' => '',
          'id' => '',
      ), $atts ) );

      $class = $class ? " class=\"$class\"" : NULL;
      $id = $id ? " id=\"$id\"" : NULL;

      return "<div$class $id>$content</div>";
  }
  add_shortcode('div', 'create_div');
```

And in the page.php i want to do something like this:

```
<div>
  <?php the_shortcode(); ?>
</div>
```

*Thanks, Andrea*

Comment: sample code plz

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at this link to know how to make a minimal code sandbox https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Dean here you go, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shortcode directly in php using the `do_shortcode()` function - see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

You can also try `get_the_content()` to get everything into a variable and then extract what you need from there - see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: Thank you so much!
If i have more of the same "div" shortcode how can i call only one of them?

Comment: I would add different attributes for each shortcode, as seen here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Also, if you just need a way to add a small amount of content to your posts, I would consider using a custom field (the easiest way would be using a free plugin like ACF - Advanced Custom Fields)